# investigation of a potential change of measured values: only the simple linear regression or also compare the mean of follow-up values with baseline?

Tags: regression, wilcoxon-signed-rank

For my medical dissertation I am studying a group of 36 patients. The patients received a drug repeatedly over several months. Serum levels of two cytokines were measured in the patients both before treatment initiation (=baseline levels) and also during the further course of treatment at different, non-standardized time points. I am pretty sure that the data are not normally distributed.

One of my tasks is to investigate whether there is a change in cytokine serum levels over time that may, but is not necessarily, due to drug treatment. That is, whether patients' cytokine serum levels decrease or increase over the course of treatment compared to baseline. I am not sure if my reasoning in this regard makes sense, so I am asking.

First, I calculated the linear regressions and looked at the slopes to see wheter a change in cytokine levels over time can be detected.
However, very few slopes of the linear regressions of the different groups showed any significant change at all.

I then thought that to detect a potential treatment effect it might also be useful to compare the mean of the follow-up cytokine serum levels (under drug treatment) with the mean of the baseline values (before drug treatment) to see if the folow-up values differ significantly from the baseline value.

However, I am not sure if the comparison is redundant if I have already examined the slope of the linear regression, or not.

My consideration was that the analysis of the change in slope of the simple linear regression of cytokine serum levels is suitable to detect a continuously increasing change in cytokine serum levels in one direction (rise or decline) that occurs over the entire time course and increases with the duration of drug administrations.
I thought that contrary to this, the comparison of the means of relative follow-up cytokine serum levels, measured after treatment initiation, to baseline values, measured before treatment initiation, is well suited to detect an overall change in cytokine serum levels in one direction (rise or decline) that occurs after treatment start regardless of whether the corresponding change happens continuously in the follow-up measurements and persists and increases with the duration of drug administrations or whether the change occurs only once after treatment start and leads to a decrease or increase in follow-up values.

However, I am not sure whether my considerations make sense, or if i have misunderstood what linear regression means. Does the linear regression only detect/represent a continuously existing and accordingly increasing change, or does it also detect a one-time and then stagnating change?

->  1) Accordingly, the question is, is the additional comparison of the follow-up values with the baseline values useful or redundant?

->  2) If this analysis makes sense, which test can I use for it? I read that for dependent, not normally distributed variables, the Wilcoxon signed-rank test would be suitable, do you agree?

Moreover, i was also unsure if it makes sense to calculate relative values from the measured absolute serum levels for a better interindividual comparability, i did that, but i am not sure if my considerations are conclusive.

Absolute cytokine levels were measured in pg/ml serum. Under the thought that absolute cytokine serum levels may be strongly influenced by "outliers", i.e. individual patients with particularly high or particularly low absolute cytokine serum levels and that analyzes of changes in cytokine serum levels may therefore be distorted because the follow-up values of the individual patients have poorer interindividual comparability, making it more difficult to detect potential minor treatment effects I built relative values.
To transfer the changes in the absolute cytokine levels of the individual patients into inter-individually comparable values, the absolute cytokine levels were related to the respective individual baseline cytokine level, measured before the first drug application. Therefore, the absolute cytokine levels of each patient were divided by the respective baseline level. I tought relative cytokine serum values related to the baseline value have better interindividual comparability regarding changes in the patients’ cytokine serum levels during or due to treatment than absolute cytokine serum values and might therefore be more suitable to analyze changes due to potential treatment effects by enabling inter-individual comparison.

->          3) does this consideration makes sense in your eyes?

->          4) does it make sense to look at the slope oft the linear regression of both absolute and relative values, or would you say one or the other makes more sense?

->          5) If the comparison between baseline and follow-up alues (as outlined above) is useful, should I rather use the relative or the absolute cytokine values? Do I distort the calculations by normalizing the baseline values to the value 0 and thus falsify the results?

->          6) if I do the comparison between baseline and mean of follow-up values also for the relative values, I think I can not use the the Wilcoxon signed-rank test because this test examines frequencies, and by normalizing the baseline to the value of 1 for all patients, I no longer have any scattering of the frequency for the relative values at baseline. But then, which test would be suitable instead?

i would be incredibly grateful for help